Optimal coding for uniform distribution?
I have asked this in Computer science stack exchange. Here: Optimal coding for uniform distribution. My answer to the question only provides intuition. I fail to make this mathematically valid. The idea of Huffman algorithm is vague. Any idea? Here's the original solution from the solution manual.


I'm not sure where is the problem.
Intuition says that if all symbols are equiprobable, the lengths should be almost equal... exactly equal if $n=2^k$; in that case, we'd have $\ell = \log_2 1/p_i = \log_2 n  = k$. Because this in general is not possible ($\log 2 n$ is not an integer).
This intuition is made precise in the first part (which you seem to grasp ok): the lengths of the codewords differ in no more than one.
We already know that we'll have $n_1$ "shorts" codewords of length $l_1$ and $n_2$ "long" codewords of length $l_2 = l_1 +1$. We also have $n_1 + n_2 = n$
Intuition also says that, since we $\ell = \log_2 1/p_i = \log_2 n $ is not an integer, some of the codewords length will be rounded below and some above, that is $l_1 = \lfloor \ell \rfloor$.
To prove this, we use Kraft's inequality. Let $l_0 = \lfloor \ell \rfloor$.
Then
$$\sum 2^{-l_i} = n_1 2^{-l_1} + n_2 2^{-(l_1+1)}\le 1 = \sum 2^{-\ell}=n_1 2^{-\ell} + n_2 2^{-\ell} $$
This already implies $l_1 = \lfloor \ell \rfloor$ is optimal. And then we have
$$ n_1  + \frac12 n_2 = 2^{l_1} $$
Putting this together with $n_1 + n_2 = n$ you can solve for $n_1$ and $n_2$, and also for $L$.
